# Empy bytes in C struct after unsigned short (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

Can anyone please explain me this?
[image]

Apparently there is a space containing two bytes that is beeing unused after field a. Can someone tell my why is this happening and is there a way to "turn off" such behavior? I really need it to work normally.

Comment: You may want to read this: ["Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member/119128#119128).

Comment: see http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_structure_alignment_and_padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This IS "working normally". Your compiler aligns the second member `b` to optimize for speed. The default alignment for an `unsigned int` on your platform is 4 bytes, so padding bytes are added after `a`.

To turn this off, you can use [`pragma`s depending on your compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx), but don't call this "abnormal behavior".